# How to preview image before upload on ASP.NET master page content placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i preview image before upload on asp.net masterpage content placeholder using asp.net controls? I would prefer it to be automatically displayed after choosing a image from the file upload control.

Here's my code:

UploadPicture.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">

            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>

            <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server"/>

            <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button ID="upload" runat="server" OnClick="upload_Click" Text="Upload" />

            <asp:Label ID="lb_msg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: looking for [Some thing like this] (http://jqueryasp.net/demo/preview-image-upload-using-fileupload-asp-net-using-jquery.html)

Comment: While your controls are ASP.Net, your problem is not. What you are really looking for is a way to preview an image before you upload it. You might need to tag this with javascript or jquery as the problem is more clientside.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to preview the image before actual post to the server is using javascript file api. This task is not about serverside controls. You can [read here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) about js fileapi.